# Storing MySQL credentials in SAM/Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-sam

I currently have a SAM template, with a collection of Lambda function. In each Lambda function I have defined the credentials to my RDS database:

```
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: '-----.-----.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
    user: '------',
    password: '-----',
    port: ------,
    database: '----',
});
```

I'm aware this probably isn't the best thing to do - What is the standard way to store this information? Should it be contained inside of a global environment variable in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [AWS::SSM::Parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html)  OR [AWS::SecretsManager::Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html) for storing the credentials.

Add necessary permissions to your `Lambda IAM Role` and then inside your lambda you can fetch them from the respective services.

[How to securely provide database credentials to Lambda functions by using AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-securely-provide-database-credentials-to-lambda-functions-by-using-aws-secrets-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to [Cache the secrets using AWS Lambda extensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/cache-secrets-using-aws-lambda-extensions.html). This is the same process as getting the credentials in SSM Parameter Store, Secrets Manger, AppConfig, etc. It will reduce the call to the AWS Service per Lambda invocation.

[image]